# Learning Management System (LMS) Chat Application

Tags: wordpress, lms

I recently tried to integrate LMS Chat into a client's website. I created a Firebase account to be able to create a database in real time. I followed the steps in the wordpress guideline.
I repeated the steps multiple times. Unfortunately, within the page where the chat is supposed to appear, the page is constantly updating.

I've already checked that it could be the wrong placement of credentials. But as I said, I've already validated this point more than once and I'm still having problems.

Email and password authentication is active.

My real time database code:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Storage code:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase keys:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "ABCD",
  authDomain: "conversascomnpl.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://conversascomnpl-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "conversascomnpl",
  storageBucket: "conversascomnpl.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "18193018412",
  appId: "1:18193018412:web:8baca8b186554c9bceab89"
};
```

Wordpress config:
[image: Wordpress]

Someone can help me? Why its my page constantly refreshing?